# loading video files into a buffer in C++

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, directx, directshow

I am currently trying to create a program that takes a video file, usually an AVI, and trying to convert it into images. So far I got the process working perfectly and could be left alone if needed. However, I would like to see if it was possible to optimize it for speed. So my question is if it is possible to load a portion of a video file into memory chunk by chunk instead of streaming it. Maybe load up a 2 - 3 minute clip into a buffer, process it, and reuse it for the next 2 - 3 minutes of video. I have looked into Direct Show and OpenCV into loading and playing video files, but so far haven't been able to find anything regarding loading videos into a buffer. Any links to tutorials or concepts is greatly appreciated.

This will be developed on a Windows XP/7 machine if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to load a few frames, lets call it a chunk of N frames, into a queue from the disk. Once you set a limit for the buffer, you then pull the frames out and process them. You can do this in parallel by using two queues (Q1 and Q2) and two threads (T1 and T2).  While processing frames from Q1 using T2, you can load Q2 using T1. You will be doing a context-switching one queue when it is full and pull the frames out and process them while the other queue is being loaded with frames from the disk. Of course you will need to handle the threading/parallelization intricacies associated with such an approach, in which case, BOOST threading might be helpful.

Comment: I understand that, but the question I am asking is how to load the frames into the buffer.

Comment: @Seb, by buffer if you mean generally memory, what I can say is that you create a Queue of type IPLImage. Once that is available you simply push the frames there. I think of buffer in that manner.

Comment: @Wajih, That sounds like it would work. In that case would I be able to open the video file twice and have each thread queue up a portion of the needed images? Like thread 1 goes from 0:00 to 1:59 of the video file and thread 2 goes from 2:00 to 3:59 or would that be a bottle neck?

Comment: @Seb Well probably you would need to open the video file twice, but I would doubt that OpenCV would allow such a thing (don't know about directShow). The point to be noted here is that a start up Q1 would take up the first set of frames, while Q2 sits idle, once Q1 is being processed (frames being pulled out), now Q2 has a chance to be filled, then switch back to Q1 while Q2 is being processed. I don't thing there would be a significant bottle neck here. Just the startup might be slow, once Q's are full, it should be pretty fast.

Comment: @Wajih, Thanks for the help. I'll start working on the method that you mentioned and see if I get an increase in the average performance.

Comment: @Seb, well would love to hear back from you if it works, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck of an application like that is **reading the file from the disk**, and **converting each frame to an image**. You can't escape from those tasks. Unless you are doing it in the wrong way, there's nothing you can do to significantly speed up the execution of the application.

Hopefully you don't have to write those images back to the disk.

Comment: The images would have to be written to the disk at some point. In that case I'm thinking of processing a portion of the video file until the maximum amount of buffers is hit. Then process those buffers to generate the images. From their I would either repeat the process if I find the memory consumption being decent or start pushing the images to the disk before repeating the process.

Comment: Make one thread read the file and convert the frames to images, while another thread just retrieves these images and write them to the disk. Sometimes the amount of work involved in developing this systems doesn't justify the short performance increase they will provide.